# Google App Issue: Hitting 'Enter' key for submission changes app link from 'exec' to 'dev'

Tags: google-apps-script

Currently, whe the user hits the enter key to log in to a simple app, the app reloads and displays the '/dev' code, forcing the prompt "You need permission" prompt.

The app is published to allow anyone to access the app, although that is not the issue.

Here is the link to see for yourself:
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz9uKoj2mTz-nUd9sWSBjpdtqe7IlD7WlCmctcI-nhK3HxF9EI/exec

To duplicate the issue, enter some text in the input then hit enter.

I do not want to disable the enter key to solve this problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code and html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<form>` tag has an action element of:

```
action="https://script.google.com/a/msad17.org/macros/s/ScriptID_here/dev"
```

You need to remove the "dev" url from the action element, or replace it with a different one.

```
<form class="left50" id="emailForm" method="get" action="https://script.google.com/a/msad17.org/macros/s/Script_ID_here/dev">
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: The input was unnecessarily wrapped in a form with an action that linked to the app.  I wanted the form submitted with a click anyway using an onclick.  One the form was rmoved, the problem was solved.